# FInd patternf for multiple pattern of files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find, command

I need to search for multiple pattern of files and check their mtime and if it morethan 30 days then delete all the files. I am using the below command but it's deleting only one pattern of file and not all. Kindly let me know where is the mistake in my command.

```
find /root -type f \( -name "*.tgz" -o -name "*.bz2" \) -mtime +30 -print -exec rm '{}' +
```

Comment: have you tried using the `-a` *and* operator instead of the `-o` *or* operator in your `find` command?

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping parentheses in the command and adding a wildcard character:

```
find /root -type f \( -name "*.tgz" -o -name "*.bz2" \) -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \+
```

Comment: @suru1432002 what is the outcome and is there any error message?

Comment: there is no error message it only deleted files with extension .bz2  and not with .tgz

Comment: @suru1432002 can you edit your answer with some example file names that are not being deleted?